# Do I always need RewriteCond?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this snippet in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/page/([0-9]+)/$ ?yearMeasure=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/$ ?yearMeasure=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/$ ?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ ?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ ?type=post&year=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

However, when I remove the first line, the website still behaves in the same way. The URLs still remain "clean." This brings me to my question; what is the significance of RewriteCond in this snippet?

The only RewriteRule this RewriteCond affected was this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ ?page=$1 [L]
```

...when I attempted to visit `/page/2/`, it didn't work.

When I moved it above the RewriteCond as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ ?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/page/([0-9]+)/$ ?yearMeasure=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/$ ?yearMeasure=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/$ ?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ ?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ ?type=post&year=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

...everything came back to normal. Why?

Comment: Every `RewriteRule` is there to support a particular type of URL. If you provide all those cases then it will be easier to understand and suggest whether a `RewriteCond` is required or not.

Answer (score 2):

In the docs `RewriteRule` is defined this way:

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
```

If `Pattern` matches the url requested (<strike>domain.com</strike>/path/file.cgi), the url is replaced with the `Substitution` (either a redirect header is returned or the url is changed internally depending on the flags)

This rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/page/([0-9]+)/$ ?yearMeasure=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

will check if the url matches the pattern and the replacement will occur only in this case. That's why here such `RewriteCond` is useless:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
```

It's useful in situations that `RewriteRule` can't capture like checking the hostname or whether a file exists:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples-2/